# Why do my TCP connections fail when UDP/ICMP work with policy routing setup?

Tags: networking, routing, nat, iproute

I have a very nasty problem where I cannot wrap my head around. My goal is to separate my main routing table from the default gateway by putting the default gateway in a separate table (so I can later have multiple default routes in multiple tables) and choose based on a policy.

For this simplified example I have just two interfaces: eth0.2 is WAN (DSL with public IP) and eth0.3 is LAN:

```
$ ip -4 addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: vrf_sonic: <NOARP,MASTER,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65575 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 brd 127.255.255.255 scope host vrf_sonic
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: eth0.2@eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master vrf_sonic state UP group default qlen 1000
    inet 192.184.144.21/21 brd 192.184.151.255 scope global dynamic eth0.2
       valid_lft 19730sec preferred_lft 19730sec
6: eth0.3@eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    inet 10.227.79.2/24 brd 10.227.79.255 scope global eth0.3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Since the default route on eth0.2 is assigned dynamically via DHCP, I use a VRF on the interface/DHCP instance. The result is that my default route lands in a table 170:

```
$ sudo ip vrf
Name              Table
-----------------------
vrf_sonic          170
$ sudo ip route show table 170
default nhid 38 via 192.184.144.1 dev eth0.2 proto static metric 20
broadcast 127.0.0.0 dev vrf_sonic proto kernel scope link src 127.0.0.1
127.0.0.0/8 dev vrf_sonic proto kernel scope link src 127.0.0.1
local 127.0.0.1 dev vrf_sonic proto kernel scope host src 127.0.0.1
broadcast 127.255.255.255 dev vrf_sonic proto kernel scope link src 127.0.0.1
broadcast 192.184.144.0 dev eth0.2 proto kernel scope link src 192.184.144.21
192.184.144.0/21 dev eth0.2 proto kernel scope link src 192.184.144.21
local 192.184.144.21 dev eth0.2 proto kernel scope host src 192.184.144.21
broadcast 192.184.151.255 dev eth0.2 proto kernel scope link src 192.184.144.21
```

My main table will contain lots of OSPF routes but for now it's just one entry:

```
$ sudo ip route show table main
10.227.79.0/24 dev eth0.3 proto kernel scope link src 10.227.79.2
```

Now my rules look like this:

```
$ sudo ip rule
101:    from all lookup local
102:    from all lookup main
104:    from all lookup vrf_sonic
1000:   from all lookup [l3mdev-table]
2000:   from all lookup [l3mdev-table] unreachable
```

First, a local table (=directly connected interfaces) is checked. Then the main routing table. And then vrf_sonic which contains the default route (and is basically a catch-all). Rules 1000/2000 are automatically inserted (due to VRF) but should never be used, due to the 104 catch-all rule.

Firewall tables are all on ACCEPT, mangle table is empty and nat table is empty too.

So far so good. ICMP (ping) works:

```
$ ping 142.250.189.164
PING 142.250.189.164 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 142.250.189.164: icmp_seq=1 ttl=113 time=4.78 ms
64 bytes from 142.250.189.164: icmp_seq=2 ttl=113 time=4.59 ms
^C
--- 142.250.189.164 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 4ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 4.589/4.683/4.778/0.116 ms
$
```

This means, as expected, the right default route is taken by selecting table 170 via rule 104.

Now comes the crazy part:

```
$ telnet 142.250.189.164 80
Trying 142.250.189.164...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Network is unreachable
$
```

This is WTF#1. But there is even a bigger WTF:

```
$ sudo ip vrf exec vrf_sonic /bin/telnet 142.250.189.164 80
Trying 142.250.189.164...
Connected to 142.250.189.164.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET / HTTP/1.0
[...]
stener("click",G)});}).call(this);</script></body></html>Connection closed by foreign host.
$
```

Which means in the context of the vrf_sonic VRF it works.
Finally I spin up tcpdump in parallel to the (failing) telnet:

```
$ sudo tcpdump -n -i eth0.2 'host 142.250.189.164'
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0.2, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
23:34:18.875675 IP 192.184.144.21.55124 > 142.250.189.164.80: Flags [S], seq 1179612779, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 333932630 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
23:34:18.879471 IP 142.250.189.164.80 > 192.184.144.21.55124: Flags [S.], seq 3829270116, ack 1179612780, win 65535, options [mss 1412,sackOK,TS val 146008037 ecr 333932630,nop,wscale 8], length 0
23:34:18.879573 IP 192.184.144.21.55124 > 142.250.189.164.80: Flags [R], seq 1179612780, win 0, length 0
23:34:19.888499 IP 192.184.144.21.55124 > 142.250.189.164.80: Flags [S], seq 1179612779, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 333933643 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
23:34:19.896597 IP 142.250.189.164.80 > 192.184.144.21.55124: Flags [S.], seq 3845107556, ack 1179612780, win 65535, options [mss 1412,sackOK,TS val 146009050 ecr 333933643,nop,wscale 8], length 0
23:34:19.896719 IP 192.184.144.21.55124 > 142.250.189.164.80: Flags [R], seq 11779612780, win 0, length 0
23:34:21.935744 IP 192.184.144.21.55124 > 142.250.189.164.80: Flags [S], seq 117], length 0n 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 333935690 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7
23:34:21.947596 IP 142.250.189.164.80 > 192.184.144.21.55124: Flags [S.], seq 3ecr 333935690,nop,wscale 8], length 0 options [mss 1412,sackOK,TS val 146011097 e
23:34:21.947717 IP 192.184.144.21.55124 > 142.250.189.164.80: Flags [R], seq 1179612780, win 0, length 0
^C
9 packets captured
9 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
$
```

Our host sends a SYN, google host replies with SYN-ACK and then **our host** sends ... a RST?! I had to rub my eyes a few times to see this correctly. WTF#3??

This is inconceivable. How can this be? What is going on here?